# Controlling the memory map of another process

Tags: linux, process, mmap, virtual-memory

Is it possible, somehow, to change the memory map of another process in Linux? As opposed, that is, to only being able to control it by way of code running in the process itself calling `mmap`.

The reason I'm asking is because I'd like to be able to build a process with a very custom memory map, and without being able to use shared libraries or even the vDSO, I don't see any way to do that inside the process itself that does not involve basically writing my own `libc` to handle syscalls and such. (Even if I were to link `libc` statically, wouldn't it attempt to use the vDSO?)

Comment: I suspect this may be possible with ptrace, though I wouldn't know the details.

Comment: @nneonneo: If it is, then the `ptrace` manpage certainly doesn't make that clear. :)

Comment: One of the dumbest (but sufficient) ways to do it would be to pause the target with `ptrace`, patch the next few instructions to include the desired call to `mmap`, and resume it. After handling the `mmap`, you unpatch the target and revert the instruction pointer. It's evil, but it would work ([this page](http://www.advogato.org/person/StephanPeijnik/diary.html?start=26) gives details on a similar technique).

Comment: Sure, but then I'd think it would be easier and cleaner to just write my own libc instead. :)

Comment: Actually you may want to write your own program interpreter (`ld.so`) instead. This program runs before the actual target and is responsible for linking everything in place (including allocating the memory map for all shared library dependencies)

Comment: Yes, I considered something like that, but I don't think it would work very well since I don't know in advance what address I'd need to map it at to avoid conflicting with the target memory layout. Also, I don't yet know how to control how and where the vDSO is mapped, though I'm in the process of exploring that.

Comment: @nneonneo Wouldn't `gdb` be more suitable then?

Answer (score 0):

`mmap` mapped memory is preserved by `fork` but wiped by system calls from the `exec` family, therefore this can't be acheived by the classic sequence `fork`, setup stuff then `exec`.

A simple solution is to use an `LD_PRELOAD` hook. Let's place this code in `add_mmap.c`.

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void add_mmap(void) __attribute__((constructor));

void add_mmap(void)
{
    int fd;
    void *addr;

    printf("calling mmap() before main...\n");
    fd = open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY);
    printf("fd=%d\n", fd);
    /* map the first 100 bytes of the file to an address chosen by the kernel */
    addr = mmap(0, 100, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    printf("addr=%llx\n", (long long unsigned)addr);
}
```

Then, build it as a dynamic library:

```
gcc -Wall -g -fPIC -shared -o add_mmap.so add_mmap.c
```

And finally run some existing program with it:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./add_mmap.so /bin/cat 
calling mmap() before main...
fd=3
addr=7fe4916f8000
```

We can check that the mapping was set up and preserved before `cat` was run:

```
$ cat /proc/27967/maps
...
7f2f7f2d0000-7f2f7f2d1000 r--s 00000000 09:00 1056387                    /etc/passwd
...
```

**EDIT**

I only show here how to add a memory mapping before the program starts, but my example can be easily extended to transparently inject a "memory manger" thread inside the program. This thread would receive orders through an IPC mechanism like a socket and manipulate the mappings accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I must admit I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: The way I understood your question is how to build a memory map and then pass it to some existing program. Maybe you should give precisions about what you are doing and what is it you expect as an answer.

Comment: Well, the direct question was if it's possible to manipulate *another* process' memory layout. :) The more generic question, which you seem to have attempted to answer, was about constructing a process' memory space completely arbitrarily, however; while your answer, as far as I can see, only deals with *adding* mappings. I must admit I don't quite see how I could reformulate the question to be more clear about that.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Ok so my answer is not totally beside the point as you said in your first comment. I showed you how to add a mapping. My example can be easily extended to transparently inject a "memory manger" thread inside the program. This thread would receive orders through an IPC mechanism like a socket and manipulate the mapping accordingly.

Comment: Certainly, but I would like to think I made it clear in the question why I had wanted to avoid the idea of controlling the memory map from within the process itself. :)